# Angular 5+ Need Component to Update on Data Change

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using an observable to populate an available tiles component from a service that gets its content from a remote json file (using json-server and localhost). This part works.

tile.service.ts:

```
 @Injectable()
export class TileService {

  tiles$ = new Subject<any>();
  details$  = new Subject<any>();
  messages$  = new Subject<any>();

  private tilesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/tiles';

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTiles(): Observable<Tile[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tile[]>(this.tilesUrl);
  }

  tileStream(data) {
    this.tiles$.next(data);
  }

  detailStream(data) {
   this.details$.next(data);
  }

  messageStream(data) {
    this.messages$.next(data);
   }

   createTile(t: Tile) {
    return this.http.post<Tile>(this.tilesUrl, t, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.error);
        console.log(err.name);
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log(err.status);
      }
    );
   }

}
```

However, when I add a new tile, the available tiles component is not dynamically updated.

available-tiles.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-available-tiles',
  templateUrl: './available-tiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./available-tiles.component.css']
})

export class AvailableTilesComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Available Tiles';

  tiles: Tile[];

  mockNewTile = {
    id: uuid(),
    title: 'GO',
    description: 'Go is an open source programming language that makes it easy to build simple, reliable, and efficient software.',
    code: {
        snippetA: 'something here.',
        }
  };

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() { // Populates available-tiles on load.  Works.
    this.tileService.getTiles().subscribe(x => this.tiles = x);
  }

  addTile(t: Tile) { // For adding tile to dashboard.
    this.tileService.tileStream(t);
    this.tileService.messageStream( t.title +  ' tile added.');
  }

  createTile() {
    this.tileService.createTile(this.mockNewTile);
  }
}
```

available-tiles.component.html

```
<aside>
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <button *ngFor="let tile of tiles" (click) = "addTile(tile)">{{ tile.title }}</button>  
  <button (click) = "createTile()">Create Tile</button>  
</aside>
```

That first click event which fires off addTile() is to populate the dashboard.  The dashboard does in fact update dynamically.

dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Dashboard';

  // Tiles to show on dashboard
  tiles = [];

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tileService.tiles$.subscribe(x => this.populateTilesArr(x));
  }

  populateTilesArr(t: Tile) {
    if (this.tiles.indexOf(t) === -1) {
      this.tiles.push(t);
    }
  }
```

Comment: inside your createTitlte you are not pushing the data to the collection

Comment: Thank you.  I need to do some refactoring as I want the array to be populated only upon successful send to the server.  At its is right now, my `tiles` array exists in `available-tiles.component.ts` and the `createTile()` method that actually sends the data to the server exists in `tile.service.ts`

Comment: so you fixed it right?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Well I know that’s the fix. Trying to figure out how to re-factor the code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who responded.  Special thanks to Richard Matsen who took time to help me sort this out.

tile.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class TileService {

  availableTiles$ = new Subject<Tile[]>();
  tilesForDashboard$ = new Subject<Tile>();
  details$  = new Subject<Tile>();
  messages$  = new Subject<any>();

  private tilesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/tiles';

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTiles(): void {
     this.http.get<Tile[]>(this.tilesUrl)
    .subscribe(tiles => this.availableTilesStream(tiles));
  }

  availableTilesStream(data) {
    this.availableTiles$.next(data);
  }

  dashboardStream(data) {
    this.tilesForDashboard$.next(data);
  }

  detailStream(data) {
   this.details$.next(data);
  }

  messageStream(data) {
    this.messages$.next(data);
   }

  createTile(t: Tile) {
    return this.http.post<Tile>(this.tilesUrl, t, this.httpOptions)
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.error);
        console.log(err.name);
        console.log(err.message);
        console.log(err.status);
        return Observable.empty();
      }).subscribe(res => this.getTiles());
  }

}
```

available-tiles.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-available-tiles',
  templateUrl: './available-tiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./available-tiles.component.css']
})

export class AvailableTilesComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Available Tiles';

  tiles: Tile[];

  mockNewTile = {
    id: uuid(),
    title: 'GO',
    description: 'Go is an open source programming language that...',
    code: {
        snippetA: 'something here.',
        }
  };

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tileService.availableTiles$.subscribe(x => this.tiles = x);
    this.tileService.getTiles();
  }

  addTileToDashboard(t: Tile) {
    this.tileService.dashboardStream(t);
    this.tileService.messageStream( t.title +  ' tile added.');
  }

  createTile() {
    this.tileService.createTile(this.mockNewTile);
    }

  }
```

available-tiles.component.html:

```
<aside>
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <button *ngFor="let tile of tiles" (click) = "addTileToDashboard(tile)">{{ tile.title }}</button>  
  <button (click) = "createTile()">Create Tile</button>  
</aside>
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Dashboard';

  // Tiles to show on dashboard
  tiles = [];

  // A property to hold the selected tile in the dashboard.
  selectedTile: Tile;

  editing = false;

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // We only want tiles that have been clicked on in available-tiles.component to show in the dashboarrd.
    // The available-tiles.component adds to the tilesForDashboard$ subject when a tile is clicked.
    // Populate the tiles array based on the data stream from the tilesForDashboard$ subject.
    this.tileService.tilesForDashboard$.subscribe(x => this.uniqueTiles(x));
  }

  // Only add a single occurence of each tile to the tiles array
  uniqueTiles(t: Tile) {
    if (this.tiles.indexOf(t) === -1) {
      this.tiles.push(t);
    }
  }

  remove(t) {
     // remove tile from array
    const index = this.tiles.indexOf(t);
    this.tiles.splice(index, 1);
    // If the value passed into remove(tile) is equal to the selectedTile, then
    // pass null to the details subject in the detailStream method of the service.
    // Otherwise, if no check performed (simply passing null) then any
    // detail showing gets removed when any tile is removed from the dashboard.
    if (this.selectedTile === t) {
      this.tileService.detailStream(null);
    }

    if (this.tiles.length < 1) {
      this.editing = false;
    }
    this.tileService.messageStream( t.title +  ' tile removed.');
  }

  displayDetails(t: Tile) {
    this.tileService.detailStream(t);
    this.selectedTile = t;
  }

}
```

dashboard.component.html:

```
 <ul>
      <li *ngFor = "let tile of tiles" (click)="displayDetails(tile)">
        <button  *ngIf="editing" class="remove" (click)="remove(tile)">X</button>
        <span class="title">{{tile.title}}</span> 
        <span class="desc">{{tile.description}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you have completely missed/left the step/code for ngZone after subscription process , that means after the change is detected for e.g. the code inside below construct

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    //Here u do the stuff after the change detection is confirmed.
});
```

You can get a good read about the changes done using ngZones in this link : https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

`http.get()` fires once then completes, so

```
this.tileService.getTiles().subscribe(x => this.tiles = x)
```

will only fire the once as well.

Maybe doing this solves the immediate need,

```js
createTile() {
  this.tileService.createTile(this.mockNewTile).subscribe(x => {
    this.tileService.getTiles().subscribe(x => this.tiles = x);
  });
}
```

and change the service so that you are returning POST completion not a subscription,

```js
createTile(t: Tile) {
 return this.http.post<Tile>(this.tilesUrl, t, this.httpOptions)
   .map(res => console.log(res))
   .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     ...
   });
```

---

***A better way***

However, likely you are posting new tiles from other locations, so subscribe to your service's `Subject` instead

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.tileService.tiles$.subscribe(x => this.tiles = x);
  this.tileService.getTiles()
}
```

and the service needs to be

```js
@Injectable()
export class TileService {

  tiles$ = new Subject<Tile[]>();

  private tilesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/tiles';

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTiles(): void {
    this.http.get<Tile[]>(this.tilesUrl)
      .subscribe(tiles => this.tileStream(tiles));
  }

  tileStream(data) {
    this.tiles$.next(data);
  }

  createTile(t: Tile) {
    this.http.post<Tile>(this.tilesUrl, t, this.httpOptions)
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        ...
      })
      .subscribe(res => this.getTiles())
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Apparently, because getTiles() returns an observable, I cannot subscribe to it. Also it needs a return value (not sure if you accidentally omitted return on the example you have). What I tried: `getTiles(): Observable<Tile[]> { return this.http.get<Tile[]>(this.tilesUrl) .subscribe(tiles => this.tileStream(tiles)); }` The error: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Tile[]>'.`

Comment: Sorry, I gave two different solutions but didn't make it clear they were alternatives.

Comment: In the first one, you can still subscribe to `getTiles()` but as I mentioned it is passing back the observable returned from `http.get()` which emits one value then completes, which is why you do not see an update when a new item is posted (completed subscriptions do not see any new values).

Comment: In the second solution, I propose you do not subscribe to `getFiles()` directly but to the Subject you have on the service. This means getFiles must pass it's value on to the Subject.

Comment: BTW @Sajeetharan is also correct, if you only want to create new titles from this one component. Obviously, you did not figure that syntax out?

Comment: Ok, getting somewhere now.  Based on your answer, the available tiles component now populates when I add the mock tile. However, the  `createTile()` method does not like `catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {` . I get `Argument of type '(err: HttpErrorResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Tile>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.` .

Comment: Ah, let me sort that out - I was winging it there.

Comment: Works ok for me. I think that it is just missing the import - `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

Comment: I have that import as well.  Typescript complains with that error I just posted.  Also, looks like i will need to create a separate subject just for adding tiles to the dashboard?  Now the dashboard is only showing an outline of a tile.  Shouldn't show anything when a tile is added to available tiles.  The dashboard should only show a tile when a tile is clicked from the available tiles list. I'll post all the component's TS files when I get this sorted out.

Comment: For the typescript error, try using `.catch((err: any)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169553/discussion-between-jeremiah2911-and-richard-matsen).

Answer (score 0):

You generally have to use NgZone when directly updating variables for them to update in the templates. If you want to get fancy you can try out the async pipe on an Observable sequence, such as using a ReplaySubject, which store all values input to it, instead of an array for tiles.

**1. Use the NgZone operator**

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private tileService: TileService, private zone: NgZone) { }
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.tileService.tiles$.subscribe(x => this.zone.run(() => this.populateTilesArr(x)));
}
```

**2. Using the async pipe with a ReplaySubject**

available-tiles.component.html

```
<aside>
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <button *ngFor="let tile of tiles | async" (click) = "addTile(tile)">{{ tile.title }}</button>  
  <button (click) = "createTile()">Create Tile</button>  
</aside>
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
...
tiles = (new ReplaySubject<any>()).distinct(); //Stores all values added, but only emits distinct ones

  constructor(private tileService: TileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tileService.tiles$.subscribe(x => this.populateTilesArr(x));
  }

  populateTilesArr(t: Tile) {
    this.tiles.next(t);
  }
```